# Extjs 4.1 Submit Form - How to get value in xtype: displayfield

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1

When i submit my form and I try to get value in php server like

```
$_POST['dis']
```

But that's undefined. I make a example of my problem in http://jsfiddle.net/LVBGr/

Here is my code

```
items: [{
    labelAlign : 'right',
    labelWidth: 72,
    width:300,
    xtype: 'displayfield',
    fieldLabel: 'How to get',
    name: 'dis',
    value: 'Hello'
}],
buttons: [{
    text: 'Submit',
    handler: function () {
        var form = this.up('form').getForm();
        var values = form.getValues();
        alert(values['dis']); // undefinded
    }
}]
```

How to get value in xtype: displayfield thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `displayfield` is configured by default to not submit any value. You can change this by specifying `submitValue: true` in the configuration.